# Contact Force of Inflating Balloon

Tags: forces, pressure, estimation

I am trying to roughly model the contact force an inflating balloon would apply on the skin. The idea is the balloon would be constrained between an in-extensible layer on one side, and the surface of the forearm on the other side (with the balloon sandwiched in between). **As I inflate the constrained balloon, is there any intuition as to how much force would be felt on the skin at different pressures?** From my understanding, a rough estimate would take the pressure of the balloon and the contact area and multiply the two to get an estimate.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What application are you using this information for?

Comment: It arose out of some discussion with a friend of mine after one of our physics courses. While I do have some applications in mind, the original question came up rather randomly, but neither us nor our professors seem to have a good intuition as to how to model this. @DavidWhite